# How to ensure that the database in django is created with utf8 collation

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, collation

I have created a database with wrong collation (not utf8) and I want django to report that on startup. How to do this a cleaner way?

I can always do some hack like checking

```
try:
    User.objects.filter(first_name__iexact="ÎÂhello") 
except OperationalError:
    print "Exit startup..."
```

Is there a better way!

Comment: It would help if you specified what database you are using as its probably a different setup depending on which one.

Comment: @wobbily_col I use both postgres and mysql !

Comment: Well, how did you set up the database in each !  We need some details to work with.

Comment: @RickJames  create database my_new_database; ALTER SCHEMA `my_new_database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ; Then run django migrations

Comment: @AbhisheshSharma - So, all the tables in `my_new_database` have inherited `latin1`?  Do you now need to change some tables?  Details, please.

Comment: @RickJames i just want to check if the database collation is utf8. If not django should not start up

Comment: @AbhisheshSharma - The connection and the columns are important, not the "database".  It may be possible to test the connection by doing a certain `INSERT` and `SELECT HEX()` to see if it inserted correctly.